# Proper way to insert massive XML into sql azure database

Tags: c#, xml, azure, bulk

Currently, our company is migrating the applications to the cloud (Azure) and we have a command-line application that does the following steps.

1. Download a file that contains a list of zipped and signed xml files with updated records.
2. If there are updated or new records
3. Download the zipped xml files
4. Unzip the xml files
5. Unsign the xml files
6. Insert each xml into a temporal table using this script within a stored procedure

   `DECLARE @bulkQuery nvarchar(max) = N'INSERT INTO #BulkTable
                                       SELECT BulkColumn 
                                       FROM Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @FilePath + ''', Single_Blob) X';`

   `EXECUTE sp_executesql @bulkQuery`
7. Merge the target table with the temporal table.

But, since I found out that the OpenRowSet command is not available in SQL Azure (I assume that this is due to SQL Azure Database doesn't have local access to the files), i tried a different approach:

Using a Web Job, the #6 step is this:

- 6.1 Load the xml into an XmlDocument object
- 6.2 Create a linq query over the XMLDocument in order to organize the records
- 6.3 For each record in the query, make an insert using LINQ to SQL.

The fact is, this second approach works, but it takes 3 hours per xml file, while the old application takes 20 minutes for all xml files. (I forgot to say that normally the app download 4 xml files and each file contains 250,000 records)

Im aware that the second approach is not the best way to do it, and I've been searching how to improve it (the right way) but I haven't found anything similar.

Hope you can help me,
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

See this forum thread if it helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/861d2307-43b9-4a87-99d9-a406ad581ea3/bulk-load-xml-files-to-sql-azure?forum=windowsazuredata

As for me, I would upload the XML file into Azure Blob Storage and then run Worker Role that would do the import.

Comment: Thank you @DixonD for your quick response. I've tried to work with the BCP and didn't succeed, it looks like the BCP only works if the xml structure is not complex, in other words, thats reason I first "preprocess" the bulked data in the stored procedure (first app) and in the linq query (second app)

Comment: The structure of the xml file is:

`<LCO>
    <Contribuyente >
            <Certificado  />
   </Contribuyente>
</LCO>`